# Running perl script with Scalar::Util fails with "Attempt to reload Scalar/Util.pm aborted."

Tags: macos, perl, homebrew

I have recently switched to a Mac Book Pro M1 (from Ubuntu) and installed Perl from homebrew.

I've installed a number of perl packages I commonly use without any issues. Unfortunately at runtime any perl programs that depend on (or use a package that depends on) Scalar::Util or List::Util fail with errors like:

```
Attempt to reload Scalar/Util.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/YAML.pm line 21.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/YAML.pm line 21.
...
```

or

```
Can't load '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/List/Util/Util.bundle' for module List::Util: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/List/Util/Util.bundle, 0x0001): symbol not found in flat namespace (_Perl_croak_memory_wrap) at /System/Library/Perl/5.30/XSLoader.pm line 96.
 at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/List/Util.pm line 24.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Scalar/Util.pm line 23.
```

I've also tried to install perlbrew as an alternative but haven't succeeded there. I've also checked that everything appears in the PERL5LIB path correctly.

With List::Util I've managed to install a newer version from CPAN but still get the same error. (The builtin Scalar::Util is the latest version)

Any suggestions on what to try to get them working I fear that it's an M1 issue but I'm not sure it could be an xcode issue I guess.

You can replicate this with:

```
$ cpanm VCSL::Which
$ vcsvimdiff -v
Can't load '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/List/Util/Util.bundle' for module List::Util: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/List/Util/Util.bundle, 0x0001): symbol not found in flat namespace (_Perl_croak_memory_wrap) at /System/Library/Perl/5.30/XSLoader.pm line 96.
 at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/List/Util.pm line 24.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/bin/vcsvimdiff line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/bin/vcsvimdiff line 12.
```

Unfortunately running

```
perl -MScalar::Util -e 1
or
perl -MList::Util -e 1
```

both run successfully. I looked at my PERL5LIB path and only see the homebrew perl paths there.

```
$ perl -E 'say join "\n", split /:/, $ENV{PERL5LIB}'

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0
```

All that looks fine with no system perl references

Comment: This output: *"dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/List/Util/Util.bundle, 0x0001): symbol not found in flat namespace (_Perl_croak_memory_wrap) at /System/Library/Perl/5.30/XSLoader.pm line 96."* indicates that it is trying to use XSLoader from the system perl (version 5.30), not the homebrew perl (version 5.34) as it should. Something is messed up... Please share the exact command you used to produce that error message

Comment: I get this with many command but here is on way to repeate:
cpanm VCS::Which
vcsvimdiff -v
This gets the second error

Comment: @IvanWills Don't add new info in comments, use the edit button and add it to your question

Comment: "Attempt to reload Scalar/Util.pm aborted."?????? Never seen that. What is giving that error?

Comment: @IvanWills *"You can replicate this with vcsvimdiff -v"*: You could check that the script is using the homebrew perl and not the system perl by printing the shebang line: `head -1 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/bin/vcsvimdiff` it should give output like: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/bin/perl`  (and not `/usr/bin/perl` aka the system perl)

Answer (score 1):

The summary:

- check that you aren't missing something
- check `perl -V` to see which perl it is and it's default module search path
- check environment variables such as PERL5LIB for conflicting values
- look in the shebang line for the programs you are running

### Do you have everything?

As Håkon noted, it looks like there are two perl installations interfering with each other. But, also as ikegami said "never seen that" error message. I haven't either, but [StackOverflow has seen it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62842326/2766176).

The entry in [perldiag] is says that the program tried to load the module, failed the first time, and then something tried again:

```
Attempt to reload %s aborted.
        (F) You tried to load a file with "use" or "require" that failed to
        compile once already. Perl will not try to compile this file again
        unless you delete its entry from %INC. See "require" in perlfunc and
        "%INC" in perlvar.
```

I don't know what keeps it from failing the first time, but you should check with something simple to see if you can load the module:

```
 $ perl -MScalar::Util -e 1
```

But, it's actually more tricky than this. Maybe that `perl` can load it, but some other `perl` can't. And, maybe you have multiple installations of Scalar::Util, but the particular `perl` and environment and program settings conspire to choose the wrong one.

### The environment can tell perl where to look

But, perhaps none of that works.

First, figure out which perl you want to use, and check its settings:

```
 $ perl -V
```

At the end of the output you should see the interesting environment settings and the default module search path. With a clean session, I don't have any environment variables that contain `PERL`:

```
  %ENV:
  @INC:
    /usr/local/perls/perl-5.36.0/lib/site_perl/5.36.0/darwin-2level
    /usr/local/perls/perl-5.36.0/lib/site_perl/5.36.0
    /usr/local/perls/perl-5.36.0/lib/5.36.0/darwin-2level
    /usr/local/perls/perl-5.36.0/lib/5.36.0
```

However, I can dirty up my environment. I'll set a `PERL5LIB` value, which prepends directories to the default module search path:

```
 $ export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1/darwin-2level:/usr/local/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1:/usr/local/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/darwin-2level:/usr/local/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/site_perl/5.10.1
```

Check `perl -V` again and this interesting thing happens:

```
Perl lib version (5.10.1) doesn't match executable version (v5.36.0) at /usr/local/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1/darwin-2level/Config.pm line 50.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

If I try to load `Scalar::Util` from the command line with `-M`, which is what I'd expect if you've mixed up the perls:

```
$ perl -MScalar::Util -e 1
Can't load '/usr/local/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1/darwin-2level/auto/List/Util/Util.bundle' for module List::Util: dlopen(/usr/local/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1/darwin-2level/auto/List/Util/Util.bundle, 0x0001): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PL_sv_no' at /usr/local/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1/darwin-2level/XSLoader.pm line 73.
 at /usr/local/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1/darwin-2level/List/Util.pm line 23
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1/darwin-2level/Scalar/Util.pm line 23.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

### Programs may be incorrectly adjusting @INC

I don't think this is a problem with `cpanm` because the world would have complained by now. However, if some program is doing funky things with `@INC`, it may be adding the wrong things.

I think the likely case for this is a set of vendor module directories they use and that some of those modules are targeted at a particular `perl`. When you use a different `perl`, you get the binary mismatch thing.

### Programs choose their interpreter

*[MacOS: two Perl installs: "Dumper.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59809285/2766176) notes that their home-brew cpanm was hardcoded to use the system perl.*

But, there's another part involved. You are running some programs, and those programs choose the perl. If you look at their first lines, they either have an absolute path to a perl, like this:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
```

Or they play a trick to find the first perl in your `PATH`:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env perl
```

I don't like that second one because I'm never sure which `perl` it will find first. In [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org), I have a long example of someone calling a program "perl", dropping it in a user-controlled directory in `PATH` (or adding that to `PATH` for you), then acting like its the real perl but turning off taint-checking along the way. Probably not your problem, but when you let the program guess who is going to handle it weird things can happen.

For example, I guess I haven't installed cpanm for v5.36.0 yet:

```
$ head -1 `which cpanm`
#!/usr/local/perls/perl-5.34.1/bin/perl
```

When I run just `cpanm`, it's going to use v5.34.1 and whatever settings I have for that.

I could tell it directly which `perl` to use, but I then need to tell that `perl` where to find the program:

```
$ perl5.36.0 `which cpanm` ...
```

Likewise, I have older versions of some programs that I address with the version I intend to use (I do a lot of stuff that runs something against many, many perls):

```
$ head -1 `which cpan5.10.1`
#!/usr/local/perls/perl-5.10.1/bin/perl


$ head -1 `which cpan5.12.5`
#!/usr/local/perls/perl-5.12.5/bin/perl
```

When you install programs, such as cpanm, the installation adjusts the shebang line for the perl that installed it. Simply running `cpanm` does not mean that you are installing into the `perl` you think you are.